# Where is the "FROM" in this code?

Tags: magento-1.7, email

I'm wondering where I can edit the "from" when the email was sent to the admin?

```
  <!--@subject Account approval for {{var customer.name}} @-->

<!--@vars

{"store url=\"\"":"Store Url",

"var logo_url":"Email Logo Image Url",

"var logo_alt":"Email Logo Image Alt",

"store url=\"customer/account/\"":"Customer Account Url",

"htmlescape var=$customer.name":"Customer Name",

"var customer.email":"Customer Email",

"store url=\"customer/account/approve/\" _query_id=$customer.id _query_key=$customer.isadminapprove _query_back_url=$back_url":"approval Url",

"htmlescape var=$customer.password":"Customer password"}

@-->



<!--@styles

body,td { color:#2f2f2f; font:11px/1.35em Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }

@-->



<body style="background:#F6F6F6; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0;">

<div style="background:#F6F6F6; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0;">

<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" height="100%" width="100%">

        <tr>

            <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding:20px 0 20px 0">

                <!-- [ header starts here] -->

                <table bgcolor="FFFFFF" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="0" width="650" style="border:1px solid #E0E0E0;">

                    <tr>

                        <td valign="top">

                            <a href="{{store url=""}}"><img src="{{var logo_url}}" alt="{{var logo_alt}}" style="margin-bottom:10px;" border="0"/></a>

                        </td>

                    </tr>

                    <!-- [ middle starts here] -->

                    <tr>

                        <td valign="top">

                            <h1 style="font-size:22px; font-weight:normal; line-height:22px; margin:0 0 11px 0;">Dear {{htmlescape var=$adminName}},</h1>

                            <p style="font-size:12px; line-height:16px; margin:0 0 16px 0;">New customer account required your approval before using it to log in to our store.</p>

                            <p style="font-size:12px; line-height:16px; margin:0 0 8px 0;">To approve the e-mail and instantly log in, please, use <a href="{{store url="customer/account/approve/" _query_id=$customer.id _query_key=$customer.password_hash}}" style="color:#1E7EC8;">this approval link.</a>. This link is valid only once.</p>

                            <p style="border:1px solid #E0E0E0; font-size:12px; line-height:16px; margin:0 0 16px 0; padding:13px 18px; background:#f9f9f9;">

                                 Customer Information:<br/>

                                <strong>Name:</strong>{{var customer.name}} <br/>

                                <strong>E-mail:</strong> {{var customer.email}}<br/>

                                <strong>Company Name:</strong> {{htmlescape var=$customer.corporatename}}<p>

                          <!--  <p style="font-size:12px; line-height:16px; margin:0;">If you have any questions about your account or any other matter, please feel free to contact us at <a href="mailto:{{config path='trans_email/ident_support/email'}}" style="color:#1E7EC8;">{{config path='trans_email/ident_support/email'}}</a> or by phone at {{config path='general/store_information/phone'}}.</p>-->

                        </td>

                    </tr>

                    <tr>

                        <td bgcolor="#EAEAEA" align="center" style="background:#EAEAEA; text-align:center;"><center><p style="font-size:12px; margin:0;">Thank you again, <strong>{{var store.getFrontendName()}}</strong></p></center></td>

                    </tr>

                </table>

            </td>

        </tr>

    </table>

</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot set the "From" part from the e-mail template.
This is not a standard e-mail template. If you created this yourself then you have to follow the same steps that magento does for sending any other e-mail.
Let's take for example the new order email

There is this line in `Mage_Sales_Model_Order::sendNewOrderEmail` (or `queueNewOrderEmail` for CE 1.9.1)

```
$mailer->setSender(Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_IDENTITY, $storeId));
```

this set's the sender details for the e-mail.
This means that the value of "from" is `Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_IDENTITY, $storeId)` that translates into `Mage::getStoreConfig('sales_email/order/identity', $storeId)`.  this means that magento looks in the config path `sales_email/order/identity` to get the sender values.  This can be managed from `system->configuration->sales emails->order->New Order Confirmation Email Sender`.
that one is a dropdown with values you find in System->configuration->store emails.  (general, sales, ....).

Each section contains a name and an e-mail.

You have to do the same for your custom template.

Comment: But this template "from" was previous named by the other developer and I need to change it to its new name From:"new" cause when I create an account the old "from" was sending to me as an admin of the site. Do you know where I can change it?

Comment: I can't guess how your module is implemented. If your previous dev did it by the book, there should be a config setting somewhere, if not...well...I have no idea. Please post in the question the code that uses that template and sends it.

Comment: where do I find that? sorry I'm still learning magento. Hope you can still help me.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Ugc5g/4142/ is this the code that sends it?

Comment: Seams like it's built correctly. Look in the `System->Configuration->Customer->Create Account (or something like that)->Sender (or e-mail identity)`

Comment: Yeah there is a settings but I can't figure out where is the "from" http://i.imgur.com/j8Q08mW.png look at this screen shot.

Comment: there is a setting called `Email sender`. try changing that.

Comment: the sender still from the old one :(

Comment: the mail is still getting the email of the admin as sender.

Comment: Sorry. I'm out of ideas. I explained what I know about the e-mail flow. I cannot do more.